# How can I update all branches when main/master has a push?

Tags: github-actions

I've tried a few things. This is what I'm using right now.

```yaml
name: Update Branches

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  update-branches:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get branch names
        id: branches
        run: |
          git ls-remote --heads origin | awk -F'/' '{print $3}' | grep -vE 'main$' > ${{ github.workspace }}/branches.txt

      - name: Update branches
        run: |
          while read -r branch; do
            git checkout $branch
            git merge origin/main --no-edit
            git push origin $branch
          done < ${{ github.workspace }}/branches.txt
```

I am getting an error if I use this:

```
error: pathspec 'reddit-fix' did not match any file(s) known to git
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

`reddit-fix` is a branch that exists.

I'd like to know if there is any way to achieve this. I've tried using an action I found on the GitHub marketplace [this one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/auto-update), but I couldn't make this work.

Comment: With `actions/checkout@v3`, use `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all the branches.

Comment: See https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage.

Comment: Thank you adding those worked. I also had to add git config --global user.email "<myemail>"
          git config --global user.name "<my_username>".

Comment: You're welcome! That's a given that you have to configure those credentials while working with `git`. Good luck!

Comment: Yup Thanks for the answer. Good Luck to you too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) answered this. I'm posting this as an answer so that I can mark the question as solved.

With actions/checkout@v3, use fetch-depth: 0 to fetch all the branches.
Also add git config --global user.email "" git config --global user.name "<my_username>".

[This](https://github.com/Wambyat/GitHub-Autoupdate-Branches) is a repo with the entire answer i.e folder structure and yml file. You can see it working in [this repo](https://github.com/Wambyat/IISC-Determining-anomalies-in-the-stock-market)